# How to pause an application when minimizing a window?

Tags: 12.10, suspend, window

I'm following an Excel video-course on my PC, so I need to have both excel and the video-course program opened in two different windows to switch from one to another. I was wondering if there is a way to automatically pause the application running the video-course when I have to minimize its window to work on Excel sheet.

In general, can ubuntu 12.10 allow to automatically suspend/pause/freeze an application when clicking on the 'minimize window' button?

Answer (score 2):

For videos specifically there is [SMPlayer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/smplayer/) that supports the functionality you're searching for. Install it via the [software center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/smplayer/) or by typing in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

Then set SMPlayer to pause when minimized by heading to *Options* -> *Preferences* -> *General* -> *Pause when minimized*:

[image]

---

I am using UMPlayer in that example, but the same procedure works with SMPlayer as well.

Here’s a screenshot from the SMPlayer Preferences dialog:

[image: SMPlayer preferences]